# NaN is removed when using na.rm=TRUE

Tags: r, nan, na, na.rm

This reproducible example is a very simplified version of my code:

```
x <- c(NaN, 2, 3)

#This is fine, as expected
max(x)
> NaN

#Why does na.rm remove NaN?
max(x, na.rm=TRUE) 
> 3
```

To me, `NA` (missing value) and `NaN` (not a number) are two completely different entities, why does `na.rm` remove `NaN`? How can I ignore `NA` and not `NaN`?

ps:I am using 64-bit R version 3.0.0 on Windows7.

**Edit:**
Upon some more study I found that `is.na` returns true for `NaN` too! This is the cause of confusion for me.

```
is.na(NaN)
> TRUE
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a language decision:

```
> is.na(NaN)
[1] TRUE
```

`is.nan` differentiates:

```
> is.nan(NaN)
[1] TRUE
> is.nan(NA)
[1] FALSE
```

So you may need to call both.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed this behaviour. My idea of missing value needs to change.

Comment: @e4e5f4 I probably would not have chosen this behavior, were I designing the language.  But it is what it is.

Comment: It is interesting to note that the help for `sum` states that `na.rm = TRUE` will remove both `NaN` and `NA` (whereas `?Extremes`) does not.

Comment: Also of interest: class(NA) == "logical"; class(NaN) == "numeric".

Comment: @neilfws That's a convenience, and another language decision.  Try `class(NA_real_)`.

Answer (score 3):

`na.rm` arguments in functions generally use `is.na()` or an analogous function.
And since `is.na(NaN) == TRUE`, you then get the behavior you're observing.

Now *should* NaN be treated as also NA?  That is a different question ;)

---

The best way around this is to explicitly tell `R` how to handle `NaN` 
One example:

```
ifelse(any(is.nan(x)), NaN, min(x, na.rm=TRUE))
```