# How to replace only NA data with 0 in R and not the NaN value in a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, nan, na

My question is that how to avoid NaN value to be changed as well when you want to change NA Value :

I used this code but it'll change both :

```
dataframe[is.na(dataframe)] <- 0
```

and I saw this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028446/nan-is-removed-when-using-na-rm-true) and get that the reason why this happen is  :

```
 is.na(NaN)
 [1] TRUE
```

but I really want to make a different between these two so I used this to change the NaN and then use the previous code

```
dataframe[is.nan(dataframe)] <-"NAN"
```

I get this error:

```
default method not implemented for type 'list'
```

so how should I do this ?

thank you in advance,

Comment: thank you @RichardScriven, yes you are right that could be done also to replace 0 where this statement is false, sorry for not to think it through first !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
dat[is.na(dat=='NaN')] <- 0
dat
 #   V1  V2  V3 V4  V5
 #1    0   6   0  9   5
 #2  NaN   9   2 10   6
 #3    4 NaN NaN  5   1
 #4   10   4 NaN  9 NaN
 #5    8   6   1  1   6
 #6    7 NaN   7 10 NaN
 #7    9 NaN   5  1   0
 #8    2   2   0  3   8
 #9    8   6   6  0 NaN
 #10   9   7   0  8   8
```

Or

```
 indx <- is.na(dat)
 dat[indx][!is.nan(dat[indx])] <- 0
```

#### data

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(1:10, NA, NaN), 
                            5*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=5))
```

Answer (score 2):

I present this as an alternative approach to @akrun's answer.

The reason you're getting the error is because `is.na` has a method for handling data.frames (`base:::is.na.data.frame`) but `is.nan` does not. (Note that a data.frame is really just a list where each named element is the same length as the others, i.e., each column.)

One problem you'll run into is that as you assign a character string to the `NaN` values in your (otherwise numeric?) data.frame, you'll be converting the remainder of each column to character. What you should be focusing on is finding the logic to *include* `NA` and *exclude* `NaN`.

There are several ways you can handle it. If all of the columns are to be processed, then the following might work for you, using @akrun's data:

```
as.data.frame(lapply(dat, function(x) {
    x[is.na(x) & !is.nan(x)] <- 0
    x
}))
##     V1  V2  V3 V4  V5
## 1    0   6   0  9   5
## 2  NaN   9   2 10   6
## 3    4 NaN NaN  5   1
## 4   10   4 NaN  9 NaN
## 5    8   6   1  1   6
## 6    7 NaN   7 10 NaN
## 7    9 NaN   5  1   0
## 8    2   2   0  3   8
## 9    8   6   6  0 NaN
## 10   9   7   0  8   8
```

Comment: Not sure whats the reasoning of using a loop instead a vectorized approach

Comment: This isn't a loop, but if you only want to run this conversion on select columns, you could use a `for` loop to iterate over specific columns, fixing them in-place.

Comment: `lapply` *is* a `for` loop

Comment: I understand your semantic assertion, so forgive my previous generalization. To me, I combine all of `*apply` as functions that operate on all elements of a vector/list/matrix/data.frame, and literal `for` and `while` to be "for" loops. One rationale against @akrun's vectorized approach is that `is.nan` just won't work on a data.frame. His approach works here, but if more control is necessary, his vectorized approach may be too indiscriminant. That's one reason I prefaced with "alternative approach to @akrun's". (One might argue `lapply` is more like a `foreach` loop, though. ;-)