# Calculating the average difference in purchase dates by customer id

Tags: r

Was wondering how I would use R to calculate the below.

1. Assuming a CSV with the following purchase data:

   ```
   | Customer ID  | Purchase Date | 
   | 1            | 01/01/2017    |
   | 2            | 01/01/2017    |
   | 3            | 01/01/2017    |
   | 4            | 01/01/2017    |
   | 1            | 02/01/2017    |
   | 2            | 03/01/2017    |
   | 2            | 07/01/2017    |
   ```
2. I want to figure out the average time between repurchases by customer.

The math would  be like the one below:

```
| Customer ID  | AVG repurchase | 
| 1            | 30 days        | = (02/01 - 01/01 / 1 order
| 2            | 90 days        | = ( (03/01 - 01/01) + (07 - 3/1) ) /2 orders
| 3            | n/a            |
| 4            | n/a            |
```

3. The output would be the total average across customers -- so: 60 days = (30 avg for customer1 + 90 avg for customer2) / 2 customers.

Comment: Could you provide us the code of your dataframe? You can get it with the `dput()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've assumed you have read your CSV into a dataframe named `df` and I've renamed your variables using [snake case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case), since having variables with a space in the name [can be inconvenient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4554977/8386140), leading many to use either snake case or [camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) variable naming conventions.

Here is a base R solution:

```
mean(sapply(by(df$purchase_date, df$customer_id, diff), mean), na.rm=TRUE)

[1] 60.75
```

You may notice that we get `60.75` rather than 60 as you expected. This is because there are 31 days between customer 1's purchases (31 days in January until February 1), and similarly for customer 2's purchases -- there are not always 30 days in a month.

#### Explanation

```
by(df$purchase_date, df$customer_id, diff)
```

The `by()` function applies another function to data by groupings. Here, we are applying `diff()` to `df$purchase_date` by the unique values of `df$customer_id`. By itself, this would result in the following output:

```
df$customer_id: 1
Time difference of 31 days
----------------------------------------------------------- 
df$customer_id: 2
Time differences in days
[1]  59 122
```

We then use

```
sapply(by(df$purchase_date, df$customer_id, diff), mean)
```

to apply `mean()` to the elements of the previous result. This gives us each customer's average time to repurchase:

```
   1    2    3    4 
31.0 90.5  NaN  NaN
```

(we see customers 3 and 4 never repurchased). Finally, we need to average these average repurchase times, which means we need to also deal with those `NaN` values, so we use:

```
mean(sapply(by(df$purchase_date, df$customer_id, diff), mean), na.rm=TRUE)
```

which will average the previous results, ignoring missing values (which, in R [include NaN values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16028466/8386140)).

Comment: This is great, thank you.   

For some reason I get an error:  

```
Error in as.character.factor(x) : malformed factor
```
  
Code: 

```
orders <- read.csv(file="/r_example.csv",head=TRUE,sep=",")

by(orders$Timestamp, orders$personIdentifier, diff) #error is Error in as.character.factor(x) : malformed factor

mean(sapply(by(orders_with_timestamp$Timestamp, orders_with_timestamp$personIdentifier, diff), mean), na.rm=TRUE) #gives warnings

```

Comment: Basically "Error in as.character.factor(x) : malformed factor" on the by( ... ) function call.  Tried to update my comment above but lost on the formatting... ha

Comment: I believe this error can only be reproduced, and therefore fixed/addressed, by having your data. If you add the output of `dput(orders)` to your question, it could help. For future reference, you will typically get better answers if you do that initially (which is why Barbara left a comment to that effect).

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I'm still new to R - I learned quite a bit from this thread. I got it everything working great by converting the field to a date field in the DF. df$purchase_date <- as.Date(df$purchase_date , "%m/%d/%y"). Then everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution with `dplyr` + `lubridate`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(Purchase_Date = mdy(Purchase_Date)) %>%
  group_by(Customer_ID) %>%
  summarize(AVG_Repurchase = sum(difftime(Purchase_Date, 
                                          lag(Purchase_Date), units = "days"), 
                                 na.rm=TRUE)/(n()-1))
```

or with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, Purchase_Date := mdy(Purchase_Date)]

df[, .(AVG_Repurchase = sum(difftime(Purchase_Date, 
                                     shift(Purchase_Date), units = "days"), 
                            na.rm=TRUE)/(.N-1)), by = "Customer_ID"]
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Customer_ID AVG_Repurchase
        <dbl>         <time>
1           1      31.0 days
2           2      90.5 days
3           3       NaN days
4           4       NaN days

   Customer_ID AVG_Repurchase
1:           1      31.0 days
2:           2      90.5 days
3:           3       NaN days
4:           4       NaN days
```

**Note:**

I first converted `Purchase_Date` to mmddyyyy format, then `group_by` `Customer_ID`. Final for each `Customer_ID`, I calculated the mean of the days difference between `Purchase_Date` and it's lag.

**Data:**

```
df = structure(list(Customer_ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2), Purchase_Date = c(" 01/01/2017", 
" 01/01/2017", " 01/01/2017", " 01/01/2017", " 02/01/2017", " 03/01/2017", 
" 07/01/2017")), .Names = c("Customer_ID", "Purchase_Date"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```